# High idle CPU usage for MongoDB on Ubuntu guest VM

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, cpu, virtualbox

I'm running an Ubuntu 12.04 server instance on VirtualBox on a OS X 10.7 host (MacBook Air 13"). The instance is configured with 512mb ram. The disk image is set to 8GB (dynamically allocated if that makes any difference) and is using 2.6GB.

I've just installed MongoDB from the 10gen repo as described here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian-or-ubuntu-linux/

I haven't changed any of the default settings as yet.

The mongod process is now running at 15-20% cpu constantly, before I've connected anything to it. I wouldn't normally have checked but it's now causing the fans to stay on whenever the VM is running.

Restarting mongodb makes no difference. Restarting the VM makes no difference.

The log is as follows:

```
Thu Jun 21 16:52:14 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1737 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=devbox
Thu Jun 21 16:52:14 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.6, pdfile version 4.5
Thu Jun 21 16:52:14 [initandlisten] git version: e1c0cbc25863f6356aa4e31375add7bb49fb05bc
Thu Jun 21 16:52:14 [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-110-9-236 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_41
Thu Jun 21 16:52:14 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log" }
Thu Jun 21 16:52:14 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
Thu Jun 21 16:52:14 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Thu Jun 21 16:52:14 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Thu Jun 21 16:52:14 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
```

I'm assuming 15-20% cpu usage at idle isn't normal, so I'd like to know if anyone has any suggestions on what to try to fix it?

*edit*
I've now converted the disk image to a fixed size VDI and it's made no difference, still at 15-20% CPU usage on the guest.

Comment: Yeah, it's unusual. I've been able to repo it on my Virtuabox Ubuntu VM running mongo 2.0.6. I can't repo it on Xen though :( I'll keep looking and let you know what I find. As a workaround, it drops to 1% when the RAM is increased to 2gb, which isn't ideal (I know).

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the problem on VMware & Xen without any luck. It seems to be a problem unique to Virtuabox. Here's an old ticket for Virtuabox that doesn't appear to have been resolved - https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/1884.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that ticket is possibly related but its the CPU usage in the guest that's at 15-20% not the host (which is more like 50% for the VirtualBox process).

Comment: I'll give parallels a try instead and see if that's any different.

Comment: I thought I'd try the mongodb package from the standard Ubuntu repo instead (v2.0.4) and that has the same issue, so it looks like it's definitely an incompatibility with VirtualBox. Parallels can't seem to migrate my virtualbox machine so I haven't managed to test it yet.

Comment: Finally got Parallels to convert my vbox disk image and when I boot in Parallels the CPU issue goes away (mongod now idling with negligible CPU usage). I would definitely prefer to use virtualbox though, so it's still a problem, this is just a workaround for now.

Comment: Hi Phil...I completely understand that it's the guest that's 15-20% CPU, not the host. As I said, I was able to replicate that no problem. As I said above, I did not see the issue in VMware or Xen. The only place that I see mongod taking high CPU when the system is idle, is when it's on Virtuabox. The ticket I referenced corresponds to this issue. I strongly believe it's a Virtuabox issue. Let me know if you agree that it's a valid answer and I'll mark it as so. I don't believe it's an incompatibility issue, rather a Virtuabox bug. Mongod is running as a simple binary with no data.

Comment: Hi Mark, that ticket seems to be more about a discrepancy between idle guest and high CPU usage of the VB process on the host, and not specifically related to mongodb idling at high CPU on the guest. While I agree that it's likely a VB bug, I believe this is a separate issue to the one described in that ticket. It's definitely a combination of VB + mongoDB that's my problem - mysql / couchdb / etc idle at 0% on the same guest VM, it's only the mongod process that runs constantly at 20% CPU.

Comment: As I mentioned above, it works fine on Parallels using the same VM image, so no doubt a VB problem - but hopefully one that 10gen can talk to VB about?

Comment: Also - please note this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/9Z7K2oXzGWQ which refers to the same issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what 10gen can do with Virtuabox but I'll see what I can find out. It's strange that it's only on Virtuabox, which is pretty much what that post says. As Eliot said it's normal for mongo to use CPU but when you compare it across platforms, anything on Virtuabox seems to be in a world of its own.

Comment: I see the same problem on Amazon EC2 M3 instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in VirtualBox on OSX as far as I can tell, I switched to Parallels and haven't had an issue since.

Comment: Interesting. I see the same thing after a clean install (38% CPU usage). I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (workstation, x64) in VMWare Workstation.